# silverlight 4 RIA update item in domaindatasource only updates after refresh

Tags: silverlight-4.0, domaindatasource

I have created a silverlight app and have a listbox that is populated using a domaindatasource. I have created a button that takes the selected list item and updates a field (in my case its called IsDeleted)
my domain service looks like this

```
  public IQueryable<Employee> GetEmployees(int storeID)
    {
        return this.ObjectContext.Employees.Where(e=>(e.StoreID==storeID)&&(e.IsDeleted==false));
    }
```

In my button event I am doing this

```
    EmployeeRecord.IsDeleted = true;
                        dsEmployee.SubmitChanges();
```

The database is  been updated as expected until the application is reloaded or I F5 than I don't see the update.
What else should I be doing to see the update straight away?

Answer (score 3):

You need to reload your domain context. Call the following:

```
myDomainDataSource.SubmitChanges((submitArgs) =>
            {
                if (submitArgs.IsComplete)
                {
                    myDomainDataSource.Load<MyType>(myDomainDataSource.MyQuery(filterTextBox.Text), System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Client.LoadBehavior.RefreshCurrent, true);
                    if (myDataSource.CanLoad)
                        myDataSource.Load();
                }
                else if (submitArgs.HasError)
                {
                    throw submitArgs.Error;
                }
            }, null);
```